# Javascript object as parent for another js object

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

Could you explain me how to do in JavaScript such thing :

1. Create one object.
2. Create second object.
3. Set first object as a parent to second object.
4. Add second object as child to first object.

It sounded simple to me as Java developer but I am confused right now.

Demo:

```js
var childFunction = function(parent){
    this.parent = parent;
    this.value = 14;
    this.fun = function(){
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=parent.value;
    };
    this.setParent = function(parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}

var parentFunction = function(){
    this.value=20;
    this.child=''; 
    
    this.addChild = function(child){
        child.setParent(this);
        this.child=child; 
    }
    
    this.setchild = function(child){
        this.child = child;
    }
    this.createChild= function(){
        this.child = new childFunction(this);
    }
}


var par = new parentFunction();
var ch = new childFunction('');
//par.setchild(new childFunction(par));
//par.createChild();
par.addChild(ch);

par.child.fun();
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Check what `this` references in each case, you might be surprised.

Comment: Code seems to be proper, what are your current issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working as of this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xs1yzf46/) as soon as you change:

```
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=this.parent.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

The current code does not pass the parent to the child in the child's constructor.

As @Axel point's out in his answer, the cause of the issue is that the variable `parent` is not bound to anything, unless you pass in a parent in the constructor's parameter named `parent`.  By passing in `parent` in the child's constructor, you create a closure for this line:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=parent.value;
```

This has been fixed below:

```js
var childFunction = function(parent){
    this.parent = parent;
    this.value = 14;
    this.fun = function(){
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=parent.value;
    };
    this.setParent = function(parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}

var parentFunction = function(){
    this.value=20;
    this.child=''; 
    
    this.addChild = function(child){
        child.setParent(this);
        this.child=child; 
    }
    
    this.setchild = function(child){
        this.child = child;
    }
    this.createChild= function(){
        this.child = new childFunction(this);
    }
}


var par = new parentFunction();
var ch = new childFunction(par);  //<-- pass parent in child constructor

par.addChild(ch);

par.child.fun();
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```